# React Swiper child component unable to update parent's state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swiper.js

I'm using [Swiper for React](https://swiperjs.com/react) and I'm trying to implement full page swiping. CodeSandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/nested-full-page-swiping-8i7sv

Basically, when you swipe left or right to Slide A or C, it should disable vertical swiping, and should only be enabled when you're on Slide B on any row.

For some reason, the state for my parent component is not updating correctly upon being triggered by the `onSlideChange` event. I've tried the other events such as `onSlideChangeTransitionEnd` but the `vertSwipe` state is not being updated correctly.

I've done this before in the exact same manner with some other components so I'm not entirely sure why in this case a child component updating the state for a parent component is not working. I've tried wrapping the state setter in a function and passing down that function instead, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Appreciate any help, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Code Sandbox demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nested-full-page-swiping-8i7sv).

I managed to get it working. The child Swiper will basically hit the parent Swiper with `swiper.enable()` or `swiper.disable()`. I believe this is the most performant way of getting this done as this does not trigger a re-render, and actually works quite elegantly.